# Moore fsm VHDL Testbench

Tags: vhdl, fsm

Hello i got this FSM.

[image]

I wrote the VHDL code :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity fsm is
    port(
            clk, reset : in std_logic;
            level : in std_logic;
            Moore_tick: out std_logic
);
end fsm;

architecture rtl of fsm is

    type stateFsm_type is (s1, s2, s3); -- 3 states are required
    signal stateFsm_reg, stateFsm_next : stateFsm_type;

begin
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if (reset = '1') then -- go to state zero if reset
            stateFsm_reg <= s1;
        elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then -- otherwise update the states
            stateFsm_reg <= stateFsm_next;
        else
            null;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(stateFsm_reg, level)
begin
        -- store current state as next
        stateFsm_next <= stateFsm_reg; -- required: when no case statement is satisfied

        Moore_tick <= '0'; -- set tick to zero (so that 'tick = 1' is available for 1 cycle only)
        case stateFsm_reg is
            when s1 => -- if state is zero,
                if level = '1' then  -- and level is 1
                    stateFsm_next <= s2; -- then go to state edge.
                end if;
            when s2 =>
                Moore_tick <= '1'; -- set the tick to 1.
                if level = '1' then -- if level is 1,
                    stateFsm_next <= s3; --go to state one,
                else
                    stateFsm_next <= s1; -- else go to state zero.
                end if;
            when s3 =>
                if level = '0' then -- if level is 0,
                    stateFsm_next <= s1; -- then go to state zero.
                end if;
        end case;
    end process;
end rtl;
```

So i compiled the code without errors. Currently i am trying to create a testbench so to be able to get the visuals so to be sure that it is workign correctly. 
This is the code that i wrote for the testbench.

```
[![library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity fsm_tb is
end fsm_tb;

architecture fsm_arch_tb of fsm_tb is
component fsm is
  port(
        clk, reset : in std_logic;
        level : in std_logic;
        Moore_tick: out std_logic
);
end component;

signal clk: std_logic :='1';
signal reset: std_logic :='0';
signal level: std_logic :='0';
signal Moore_tick: std_logic ;
type stateFsm_type is (s1, s2 , s3 ); -- 3 states are required
signal stateFsm_reg, stateFsm_next : stateFsm_type ;

constant clk_period : time := 1 ns;

begin

cnt_inst : fsm
  port map (
      clk, reset, level, Moore_tick
  );

clk_gen: process is
begin
      clk <= '1';
      wait for clk_period/2;  --for 5 ns signal is '0'.
      clk <= '0';
      wait for clk_period/2;  --for next 5 ns signal is '1'.
end process clk_gen;

trig: process is
begin

          wait for clk_period;
           level<= '1';     
      wait for clk_period;
       reset <= '0' ;
           level <= '1' ;
      wait for clk_period;
           level <= '1' ;
      wait for clk_period;
           level <= '1' ;
      wait for clk_period;
           reset <= '1' ;
      wait for clk_period;
           reset <= '0' ;
       level <= '1' ;
      wait for clk_period;
           level <= '1' ;
      wait for clk_period;
           level <= '1' ;
      wait for clk_period;
           level <= '1' ;


         wait;
end process trig;

end architecture fsm_arch_tb;
```

But i am stuck on the last process.
I am trying to implement the `trig process` so to be able to see all the transitions on waveforms

[image]

Comment: So far you don't appear to be [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and are [simply stating you are stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  What's got you stuck? Note that Moore_tick is an output from fsm and assigning it in the testbench creates a second driver where the value of the signal will the resolution of the two drivers.

Comment: Testing all the branches in your state machine can be done by [manipulating reset and level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TYCZ.jpg) and not driving Moore_tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the test bench, you are trying to assign a value to the signal type **out**

Remove these:

<strike>Moore_tick <= '0';</strike>

<strike>Moore_tick <= '1';</strike>

Comment: Hello i made the changes that you sugggested. and i get these waveforms. 
Why i dont get output values for the  `stateFsm_reg` and the `stateFsm_next` thought?

Comment: In yout testbench, you have declared the signals `stateFsm_reg` and `stateFsm_next` as **std_logic**, instead they should be of your declared type **stateFsm_type** (as in your rtl code)

Comment: Hello again i changed the signals i added 
`type stateFsm_type is (s1, s2 , s3 ) `
`signal stateFsm_reg, stateFsm_next : stateFsm_type ;`
 i get output `s1` but it does not change. All the time is `s1`

Comment: changed code and/or relevant figures might be more helpful to provide answers

Comment: In your test bench, you are trying to create the signals `stateFsm_reg` and `stateFsm_next` internally but you haven't mapped them to any of the signals of your entity. So, either you need to output the signals `stateFsm_reg` and `stateFsm_next` in your entity and then map them with the ones in the test bench or you need to remove the signals from test bench and manually add these in the ModelSim from Instance/Objects area or using command line `add wave ../..`

Comment: I found the solution. I did not add the uut at waves. Thank you so much for your time and your responses!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184112/discussion-between-sai-varun-and-ioan-kats).